# React ts + node js (back) + nginx on one domain

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment, devops

I can’t fully understand the nginx configs so that the back and front work together

Well, I wrote a configuration for the front, added it first for port 80, added a certificate and everything works

path: /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server {

        root /var/www/booking-1/frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name bookhotel.kg www.bookhotel.kg;

           location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.bookhotel.kg/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.bookhotel.kg/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.bookhotel.kg) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = bookhotel.kg) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name bookhotel.kg www.bookhotel.kg;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Next, I wrote the configuration for the back-end, this is where the main problem arose for me, I don’t know where exactly and how to write it correctly so that everything works on the https protocol. At the moment the configuration is like this and it is located here

path: /etc/nginx/conf.d

Backup is running on the server using pm2

```
#server{
#location /app/ {
#        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
#        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
#        proxy_set_header Host $host;
#        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#        proxy_pass   http://195.38.165.48:8000/;
#
#  }
#}

server {
    server_name bookhotel.kg;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://195.38.165.48:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests";
    }
}
```

I also tried this configuration which also did not give any result

```
server {

        root /var/www/booking-1/frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name bookhotel.kg www.bookhotel.kg;

           location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }


   location / {
        proxy_pass http://195.38.165.48:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests";
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.bookhotel.kg/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.bookhotel.kg/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.bookhotel.kg) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = bookhotel.kg) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name bookhotel.kg www.bookhotel.kg;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I need to set up the config so that when receiving an SSL certificate, the connection between the back and front is protected

Now I'm getting this error
[image]

Comment: Okay, I figured out the configuration, but the backend still doesn’t want to work on https)